# TFS 2012 Lab Center Error - There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I'm doing experiment on TFS 2012 Lab Environments to setup BDT workflow.

When I setup standard environments and test BDT successfully on Lab Center, I try to setup a new environments with the existing VMs which has been used by existing environments.

So I have to delete the existing environments to release the VMs first. But after the deletion, the lab center is  opened with the following exception:

**Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

There is a same issue reported at [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786403/application-detected-an-unexpected-fault-when-opening-the-lab-center-mtm-2012), but it has not been resolved.

Could you please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experiments, the issue is resolved by following the suggestion in the [post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786403/application-detected-an-unexpected-fault-when-opening-the-lab-center-mtm-2012):
The issue seems caused by the bug of TFS that it is not deleted the environments totally and some dirty data is left.

- Connect to TFS db
- Run the following sql to check the Env data:

`Select le.LabEnvironmentId from LabEnvironment le where le.PartitionId = 1 And NOT EXISTS (Select * From LabSystem ls where ls.LabEnvironmentId = le.LabEnvironmentId AND ls.PartitionId = 1)`

- At last run the following sql to delete un-valid environments data:

`Select le.LabEnvironmentId from LabEnvironment le where le.PartitionId = 1 And NOT EXISTS (Select * From LabSystem ls where ls.LabEnvironmentId = le.LabEnvironmentId AND ls.PartitionId = 1)`

I have tested on my TFS Evn and it works.

**Attention: before run the sql script, refine it carefully.**