# Getting error(There was an error generating the XML document) in MTM > Lab centre > lab> environments

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

In MTM when tried to access Lab environment I got the below error message :

> Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

[image]

I did check the solution in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872331/tfs-2012-lab-center-error-there-was-an-error-generating-the-xml-document) link. But it suggests that I should delete the environments using sql queries, which I don't want to do (and also I don't have access to database).

Can anyone please suggest some other way of fixing it.

Note : This is happening with most of the projects present in collection however for 2 projects it is not giving any error in MTM Lab centre

Comment: Do you have the same issue in other machines that has the VS (include MTM) installed on them?

Comment: yes, I am getting same error message in all the machines

Answer (score 0):

You can try below things to narrow down the issue:

**1. Try to clear TFS cache in your client machine, then try it again.**

The corresponding Tfs folders to manually delete are as follows:

```
Tfs 2017: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache\"
Tfs 2015: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\"
Tfs 2013: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache\"
Tfs 2012: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache\"
```

You can copy and save the following content to a `.bat` file, then execute on the client machine to delete the caches.

```
@echo off
ECHO **********************************************************
ECHO Delete the Tfs 2017 client cache
ECHO **********************************************************
rmdir "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache\" /s /q
ECHO "All Done!"
```

**2.  [Querying Lab Environments Using TFS Lab Management APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/04/02/querying-lab-environments-using-tfs-lab-management-apis/), then compare with the environments in MTM, to check if there are any differences (NOT EXISTS ones).**

**3. Delete Lab Environments with  [`tfsconfig lab /delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=tfs-2018#lab-delete) command.**

- This command will remove all group hosts, library shares, and environments from team project collection.
- Recreate the lab environments, see [Creating Lab Environments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380688.aspx)

If that still doesn't work, then I'am afraid that you have to ask the admin to grant the permission to access the database, then try the solution mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872331/tfs-2012-lab-center-error-there-was-an-error-generating-the-xml-document).

Comment: I tried with [Querying Lab Environments Using TFS Lab Management APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/04/02/querying-lab-environments-using-tfs-lab-management-apis/) but the code given in same error which I am getting in MTM when I trying to get the list of environment in the code "ICollection<LabEnvironment> envList = labService.QueryLabEnvironments(querySpec);" the error message is  "Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: I tried point one already but it didn't work also about point 3 - I cannot delete all the environments. Is it possible to delete environment by specific name from a particular project present in tfs instead of deleting all of them?

Comment: @PankajDevrani As far as I know, no such commands to delete environment by specific name. In this case I suggest asking admin to grant permissions to access the DB. Then backup the database first and try the solution mentioned in the link.

Comment: Also I use VSTS can you tell how can it be done in VSTS?

Comment: @PankajDevrani Unfortunately for VSTS we cannot manage the DB directly. Have you tried other user account? Just check if other team members have the same issue.

Comment: Yes I did tried the other accounts and all are facing the same issue.

Comment: @PankajDevrani Seems it's an VSTS issue. Suggest you submitting a feedback/defect to developercommunity : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html